# qBittorrent. How to download skipped files?

Tags: qbittorrent

I have skipped some files on my initial download dialog with qBittorrent, but it turns out I needed them. How can I set this files to start downloading and stop being skipped?

Answer (score 0):

I made it to force recheck the torrent and not the right click option is available. I have no idea what was it.